# Equipment reliability in medical device manufacturing setting

Tags: sampling, sample-size, survey, reliability, minitab

I am working in a medical device company and there is something that I would like to test out on the manufacturing line. I am not a statistics expert so this is something that is out of my skillset.

In the past, we have always had this equipment "X" (to keep a level of confidentiality) that is used in a production line right now. I want to put in an equipment "y" of a similar nature in place of it to test the reliability of this equipment, to check whether we are experiencing similar levels of breakdowns or more. Now I understand that standard machine capability study has a minimum of 30 samples and ideally 50 samples, however, we want to be able to test in volume as we cannot guarantee that those breakdowns will happen within 50 samples as we also want to gauge wear and tear.

Now I want to check with the Statistics GURUs here how I would go about looking at an appropriate sample size determination. Given that this is medical device industry we probably want to have a high confidence level and Acceptable Quality Level (AQL). Note that

1. We do not have a log of previous breakdowns, short of trawling through breakdown call outs
2. We could just run both equipment the same amount of time and compare the 2 but it is hardly indicative of the reliability as sometimes equipment failure can be due to chance.
3. One shift produces about 700 products
4. there are 3 known failure modes for this equipment
5. If need be, I have access to MiniTab as a statistical software

What I have thought of doing is using a Survey Sampling method, where I take a population size of say 1 million, 95 Confidence and 1% Error, and from using a simple calculator it gives me 9513 samples. Because in my understanding, this means that if out of the 9513 samples, there were 12 breakdowns, I can say with 95% confidence that the overall 1 million population can have 11 to 13% breakdowns. Is this a good way to go about it?

Thank you all, and hope to hear from you soon.